# Trix Editor on Rails: Text flows outside box on Heroku (not localhost)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just implemented Trix editor in my rails app and it works perfectly on `localhost` but is pulling this ugly business on Heroku:

[image]

I can only imagine this is to do with the asset pipeline, so the basics are that I did install the gem (`gem 'Trix'`) and did `bundle install`, I added `//= require trix` in my `application.js` and `*= require trix` in my `application.css.scss`.  My assets precompiled upon pushing things to Heroku.

Here's the entire `application.css.scss` structure:

```
*= require magnific-popup
 *= require trix
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'ionicons';
```

Other than these basics, can anyone figure out what step I'm missing to get the styling to appear on Heroku?

Comment: Can you add your assets/stylesheet folder structure in your post?

Comment: Try by removing `*= require_self` and `*= require_tree` from your application.css.scss file.

Comment: @ChetanDatta, added my assets, as requested.

Comment: can you give link to heroku site?

Comment: @RockwellRice, you can see the issue at http://www.thefamilyzone.net/quotes.  Try to create a new quote and the text will overlap the box after a few lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a style being applied to a class `.form-control` that is setting height on that box at `34px`. Which is why it does not grow with the text

When I remove the height property that the box gets then the box expands out around the text again.  This can be kind of hard to find and fix from my end but it is located in a file `application.css` file inside a block with the same styles that this is surrounded by, probably not line 5 though, probably a later line but depends on file size, search for `height: 34px` or just `34px` again or something and look for a block of styles like the one in the image here and remove that line (now keep in mind if this line is used as a style somewhere else then that will break).

[image]

That should fix the issue.

If you are not familiar with using chrome (or any browsers) dev tools I would recommend finding any reference and getting comfortable with using them, they are perfect for debugging this kind of thing.

Comment: You are a lifesaver, sir!  Thank you.  I had forgotten to remove the `.form-control` when adding Trix!